# Start Tk.mainloop() thread with another thread

Tags: multithreading, tkinter

I want to exec some code while Tk.mainloop() is running, so I think I need threading module.

I tried to put `Tk.mainloop()` inside the `run` method of a thread class and then I put the code I want to run while mainloop is running inside another thread.

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run():
        # window is tk.Tk()
        window.mainloop()

class MyCode(Thread):
# my code

TkinterThread = MyThread()
TkinterThread.start()
OtherThread = MyCode()
OtherThread.start()
```

and tkinter report me an error

`RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different apartment`

so I searched on internet and I understand that the mainloop can be runned only out from thread becouse work in only one of them.
So, is there a way to run others thread while mainloop is running?

Answer (score 1):

You can run code in other threads. The problem isn't so much multiple threads *per se*, but that you've got tkinter code in more than one thread. All tkinter code needs to be in a single thread.

Usually it's best to make that your main thread (both creating the widgets and starting `mainloop`), and run your other code in a secondary thread or process. You can use a thread-safe queue to send information between the threads, such as when passing results back to the GUI.